# React-Scripts and Jest - No tests found on running npm test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, redux, jestjs

I am testing *reducers* and *storage*.
I read the `jest` [tutorial-react](https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-react) manual and it's a little different from mine, but I also found information that "react-scripts test" should also work

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "jest": "^27.4.7",
    "miragejs": "^0.1.43",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "seedrandom": "^3.0.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "^0.6.5",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1"
  }
```

**Commands**

```
npm test
npm test --config jest.config.js
npm test --setupFile ./src/setupTests.js
npm test --setupFiles ./src/setupTests.js
```

**Output**

```
Active Filters: filename .\\src\\setupTests.js/
 › Press c to clear filters.
 
Watch Usage
 › Press a to run all tests.
 › Press f to run only failed tests.
 › Press o to only run tests related to changed files.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.
```

On pressing "a",

```
No tests found, exiting with code 0

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

**./jest.config.js**

```
// Sync object
/** @type {import('@jest/types').Config.InitialOptions} */
const config = {
    setupFiles: ['./src/setupTests.js'], 
    verbose: true,
};

module.exports = config;
```

**./src/setupTests.js**

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
    expect(1 + 2).toBe(3);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the Jest documentation says about how it finds test files:

> By default it looks for `.js`, `.jsx`, `.ts` and `.tsx` files inside of `__tests__` folders, as well as any files with a suffix of `.test` or `.spec` (e.g. `Component.test.js` or `Component.spec.js`). It will also find files called `test.js` or `spec.js`.

Since the `setupTests.js` filename does not meet this criteria, Jest does not recognize it as a test file. If you rename the file to end with `.test.js` or move it into a `__tests__` folder, Jest should be able to find it and run the test. If you need to keep the filename as is, this default behavior can be changed by setting `testRegex` in `jest.config.js` (read more about this setting [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testregex-string--arraystring)).

The `setupFiles` property in `jest.config.js` is used for setting up the environment before the tests actually run. The documentation for that setting can be found [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfiles-array), but it doesn't appear to be necessary to do any setup for this case based code you provided.